# How do I integrate gerrit to my github repository?

Tags: github, gerrit

I would like to know what do I need to do in order to integrate gerrit to an existing github repository.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What about [GerritHub](http://gerrithub.io/)? Is it an option?

Comment: But do you know how can I send all my pushs directly to a review?